# solve the inequality of $3e^{2x}+6e^x-12\leq 0 $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

i would like to solve the inequality of exp :

$$3e^{2x}+6e^x-12\leq 0 $$

let $X=e^x$

we got

$$3X^2+6X-12\leq 0$$

we try to solve the equation :

$$3X^2+6X-12=0$$

$\Delta=180$ then

$X=-1-\sqrt{5} $ or $ X=-1+\sqrt{5}$

thus   $$(X-(-1-\sqrt{5})(X-(-1+\sqrt{5}))\leq 0$$

$$(X+(1+\sqrt{5})(X-(-1+\sqrt{5}))\leq 0$$

$$(e^{x}+(1+\sqrt{5})(e^{x}-(-1+\sqrt{5}))\leq 0$$

study of product:

- $(e^{x}+(1+\sqrt{5}))$ this hold for any $x \in R$ since $e^{x}>0$ then $x \in \mathbb{R}$
- $(e^{x}-(-1+\sqrt{5}))\leq 0$
  then 
  $e^{x}-(-1+\sqrt{5})\leq 0$
  $x\leq  ln(-1+\sqrt{5})$

thus $x \in (-\infty,ln(-1+\sqrt{5}))$

$$S=(-\infty,ln(-1+\sqrt{5})) \cup  R=R$$

with $ln=\log_{e}$

am i right

Answer (score 0):

You're almost correct,since you've $(e^x+(1+\sqrt{5}))(e^x-(1+\sqrt{5}))$ and you know that $e^x+1+\sqrt{5}> 0$ hence you must have $e^x-(1+\sqrt{5})\leq 0$,if it's bigger than $0$ then the whole expression is bigger then zero hence the answer is $\mathbb{R}\cap(-\infty,\ln(-1+\sqrt{5}))=(-\infty,\ln(-1+\sqrt{5}))$